# FILE pointer incompatible with stdin

Tags: c, gcc, stdin

I have the following code

```
struct FILE *in, *out;

if (argc == 1) {
    /*  No files were supplied so assume parsing from the stdin and printing to the stdout */
    in = stdin;
    out = stdout;
}
```

However when compiling with gcc using flags `-ansi -Wall -Wextra -Werror` the following error occurs: `assignment from incompatible pointer type`.

I looked up on the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf&ei=z672Us_VFrKe7Abng4FA&usg=AFQjCNEeMdOXHhmmsu9aFZia3FnZdPSDBA&sig2=QvMoLA-00fcVhk076MwlnQ&bvm=bv.60983673,d.ZGU) for the type of `stdin` and on page 227 (251 on Adobe Reader) the type in indeed `FILE *` so I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Compiling with the specified flags complains if `struct` is not present as it doesn't recognize `FILE` as a type

Comment: @TimCastelijns Because it's C (not C++)

Comment: FILE is a typedef, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rob Ive used `FILE`s in c, but never with struct

Comment: Ah, it's a typedef. Yes. Drop the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `struct` and include `stdio.h` to get the typedef.

Comment: If I drop `struct` the compiler complains because of the `-ansi` flag, and I include `stdio.h` before, this is just the snippet of the code where the compiler complains

Comment: @RuiRosário Make a complete short example and edit your question. Also add the exact error message that you get.

Comment: Actually there is no need for it. I updated my MinGW and tried compiling without the `struct` and it worked, must have been because of the gcc version I had from my University